# I am scrping linkedin profiles but got the error

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to scrape the linkedin profiles based on specific keywords but got the error here is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tkinter import *

class Linkedin():
    def getData(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/danish-khan/scrapers/researchgate/chromedriver')
        driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/login')
        driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('danishkhankd237@gmail.com') #Enter username of linkedin account here
        driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('dankhanish446')  #Enter Password of linkedin account here
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()

        #*********** Search Result ***************#
        search_key = "data analyst" # Enter your Search key here to find people
        key = search_key.split()
        print('\nkeyword:', key)
        keyword = ""
        for key1 in key:
            keyword = keyword + str(key1).capitalize() +"%20"
        keyword = keyword.rstrip("%20")
        print('\nkeyword2 :', keyword) 
           
        #global data
        data = []
        profile_links = [] 
         
        for no in range(1,3):
            start = "&page={}".format(no) 
            search_url = "https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords={}&origin=SUGGESTION{}".format(keyword,start)
            driver.get(search_url)
#            driver.maximize_window()
            for scroll in range(2):
                driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
                time.sleep(2)
            search = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
            for people in search.findAll('span', class_ = 't-16'):
                profiles = people.find_all('a', attrs = {'class' : 'app-aware-link'})
                count = 0
                for i in profiles:
                  profiles2 = i['href']
  
                  print(profiles2)    
                  profile_links.append(profiles2)
                print("Going to scrape Page {} data".format(no))
                
                print('\nprofile_links :', profile_links)
                lent = 0 
                for people in profile_links:
                     #count = 0 
#                    if count%2==0:
#                      lent+=1
                  print('Profile :', people)                      
              
                  driver.get(people)
                  print('\ngetting\n')
                  # #********** Profile Details **************#
                  card = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
                  
                  try:
                    Name = card.find('h1', attrs = {'class' : 'text-heading-xlarge inline t-24 v-align-middle break-words'}).text 
                  except:
                    Name = 'None'

                  try:
                    Work_at = (card.find('div', attrs = {'class' : 'text-body-medium break-words'}).text).strip()
                  except:
                    Work_at = "None"

                  try:
                    Image =  card.find("img", attrs = {'loading' : 'lazy'})['src']
                  except:
                    Image = 'None'
                  try:
                    Education = card.find('h3', attrs = {'class' : 'pv-entity__school-name t-16 t-black t-bold'}).text
                  except:
                    Education = 'None'
                  try:
                    Location = soup.find('span', attrs = {'class' : 'text-body-small inline t-black--light break-words'}).text.strip()
                  except:
                    Location = 'None'
                  
                  details = {
                    'Name' :  'hgf', #card.find('h1', attrs = {'class' : 'text-heading-xlarge inline t-24 v-align-middle break-words'}).text,
                    'Location' : '',
                    'Work_at' : '',
                    'Education' : '',
                    'Profile_image' : '',
                    'Website' : '',
                    'Email' : ''
                  }
                  details['Name'] = Name
                  print(details)




                  time.sleep(15)               
                  driver.quit()
                
        driver.quit()
 
    def start(self):
        self.getData()
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    obJH = Linkedin()
    obJH.start()
```

firstly i want to collect all the url of the user profiles of specific kewyords like here data analyst and then go through all the profile urls to scrape specific data from these profiles but it only scrape two urls and not all the profiles urls and seconds when going through the list of urls i got the error:

```
python linkdn2.py

keyword: ['data', 'analyst']

keyword2 : Data%20Analyst
https://www.linkedin.com/in/roshaankhan?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAACL58nQBKUordklUHOqNKThOLHNSLnirIck
Going to scrape Page 1 data

profile_links : ['https://www.linkedin.com/in/roshaankhan?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAACL58nQBKUordklUHOqNKThOLHNSLnirIck']
Profile : https://www.linkedin.com/in/roshaankhan?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAACL58nQBKUordklUHOqNKThOLHNSLnirIck

getting

{'Name': 'Roshaan Khan', 'Location': '', 'Work_at': '', 'Education': '', 'Profile_image': '', 'Website': '', 'Email': ''}
https://www.linkedin.com/in/sabanasimbutt?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAAB7iVNAB_l8blfjWUwqgsV-bkjV3X_3ODdk
Going to scrape Page 1 data

profile_links : ['https://www.linkedin.com/in/roshaankhan?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAACL58nQBKUordklUHOqNKThOLHNSLnirIck', 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/sabanasimbutt?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAAB7iVNAB_l8blfjWUwqgsV-bkjV3X_3ODdk']
Profile : https://www.linkedin.com/in/roshaankhan?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAACL58nQBKUordklUHOqNKThOLHNSLnirIck
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 950, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 187, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f431515f610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linkdn2.py", line 108, in <module>
    obJH.start()
  File "linkdn2.py", line 104, in start
    self.getData()
  File "linkdn2.py", line 55, in getData
    driver.get(people)
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 397, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 79, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 171, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 330, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 747, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 747, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 747, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 719, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=56707): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/b7431e8051979e6a9a308bdfd59bf60a/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f431515f610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I have tried many ways to solve this but can't find solution.

Comment: It seems to me like a connection problem so it could be for example that that address could not be reached or that address denied connection or it got a timeout, did You even read the error message carefully? also it would be great if You could provide a [mre].

Comment: @Danish khan as a side note, you probably want to strip that password out of your code blob.

Comment: @Danish khan, do you know that linkedin can mark your login attempts as a suspicious activity. At times, linkedin asks you to verify your login va OTP. Make sure if this is not the case