# I want to go through list of url in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to go through list of urls of user profiles of linkedin but faces and error.
My code is here:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/danish-khan/scrapers/researchgate/chromedriver')

driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/login')    
  
driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('danishkhankd237@gmail.com') 

#Enter username of linkedin account here

driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('dankhanish446')  

#Enter Password of linkedin account here
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()



data = ''
with open('linkd5.html', 'r') as f:
   for line in f.read():
      data += line

results = []
search = Selector(text = data)
profiles = search.xpath('//span[@class="entity-result__title-text  t-16"]/a/@href').getall()
#profiles = [profile.xpath('@href') for profile in profiles]

print(profiles)


for prof in profiles:
    try: 
      driver.get(str(profiles))
      time.sleep(2)
    except Exception as e:
       print('error:',e)
    
driver.close()
```

When i run the code i can't get through the url links but got an error.
Here is the output error:

```
 python linkdn1.py
['https://www.linkedin.com/in/hamza-sharif-875953144?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAACMGGhkB3kxixK-mAI2cg1QYlHO0Sp4sbdM', 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/lubna-huma-a7a65311a?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAAB2j1z4Bkr_6aIv-Z1WOX7gzmhm2ayJ07Ns', 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/sabanasimbutt?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAAB7iVNAB_l8blfjWUwqgsV-bkjV3X_3ODdk', 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/amna-nazim?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAACzlukcBneVdmstgrbxBdMEQI2J92Xj7HOE', 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/sania-ahmad-09253315b?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAACZX864BzTbeJ7t1Fkd2foMu55FRTz4a2WU', 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/nehanadeem?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAAC9lGr8BjlQvEaZh9zEYInfPZBDfiv3zyIo', 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/amin-nizar-ali-b417b7165?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAACdzlKEBY-R38lMGSRjEFejlAuWKy6sRuEk', 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/maira-tanweer-b4550410b?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAABupTWUBpxgATilDl8RpgzuL1CXVyZdAZRg', 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/zahra-shah-18a583121?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAAB4pqToBoZxITHFL1cGR-RCW8nz7xG22ak8', 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/sajjal-malik?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAACYTeC0BtXpkXG7Yo81ZAeT2z5U351HdHtg']
error: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.72)

error: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.72)

error: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.72)

error: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.72)

error: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.72)

error: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.72)

error: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.72)

error: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.72)

error: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.72)

error: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.72)

  I tried to find and solve the error but can't got them. going through a single url is possible and done easily but when there is a list of urls then is not working.
```

The message invalid argument in output console i don't understand what is this error.
can anyone solve this or give me another way to do this possible i.e to go through list of urls inlinkdein and same for other websites.

Comment: You have already posted the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67548279/i-am-scrping-linkedin-profiles-but-got-the-error

Comment: After login I see no elements located by `//span[@class="entity-result__title-text  t-16"]/a/@href` even not by `//span[@class="entity-result__title-text"]`

Comment: I download a file here linkd5.html manually i scrape working on it and then i want to go through all the urls from the html file which is extracted.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this questions when i loop through list of urls without appending in list because it always a list of urls.
so it starts working.
I correct the
for prof in profiles:
try:
driver.get(str(profiles))
time.sleep(2)
except Exception as e:
print('error:',e)

here changing driver.get(str(profiles)) to  driver.get(str(prof)) starts working